# How can I tell if RAM sold on the internet is SODIMM size if it is not mentioned?

Tags: memory, hardware

How do I know if the following RAM is SODIMM size?

Manufacturers never make it simple to buy...

https://www.scorptec.com.au/product/Memory/DDR4/79106-KD4AGU880-32A160T
http://www.klevv.com/ken/products_details/memory/Klevv_BoltX.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not SODIMM.

DDR4 SODIMM has 260 pins, and its size is 69.73mm x 30.13mm. Your linked KLEVV is

> 288 Pin DDR4 Unbuffered DIMM
>
> (L) 133 x (W) 33 x (H) 6 mm

Comment: Ah so it's the number of pins... thanks!

Comment: And its dimensions.